# wrt (openwrt / lede) initramfs

Tags: kernel, initramfs, openwrt, squashfs, lede

Do you know what `initramfs-kernel` mean?
I know `squashfs-factory/squashfs-sysupgrade`.
How can I do it or what is it? which is better?

I just don't understand what the `initramfs-kernel` mean.
I have `Linksys 1900ACS v2` and `D-Link DL-860l B1`, but I only use `squashfs-factory` and `squashfs-sysupgrade`.
What does the `initramfs-kernel` mean?
When would I use those?

I would even fear to install that.

So, continuing, like `lede-17.01.2-ramips-mt7621-dir-860l-b1-initramfs-kernel.bin`, what does this mean? can i use it and if so, what is the difference between `lede-17.01.2-ramips-mt7621-dir-860l-b1-squashfs-factory.bin` (which I know what it does and how) or `lede-17.01.2-ramips-mt7621-dir-860l-b1-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin` (which I know what it does and how).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `initramfs` OpenWRT/LEDE kernel builds are including the rootfs image into `initramfs`, attaching it to the kernel so it will put the filesystem in a ramdisk during bootup and utilize it as `/`. You don't need such builds if the regular flash-based storage works for you, as it won't allow any persistent configuration by default. Such a configuration is useful during initial OpenWRT/LEDE porting efforts when you don't have the flash driver configured to use the flash chip on the device.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer then.

Comment: how can i accept???

Answer (score 2):

Initramfs kernel is like live os distro.
You can test it without installing into the sd card.
So, if you want to test the image initramfs is useful.

Answer (score 0):

That image is the same as using the toram kernel boot command except its setup before hand for quickly tossing everything and the kitchen sink straight into ram.